# php: retrieving infos from facebook group

Tags: php, facebook

i'm looking for a way to code some statistics for a facebook group which displays infos like most active member, most commented post and such.

i've tried to parse the group's email-notifications, unfortunately facebook doesn't notify on each event.

so i was thinking about curling directly from the facebook group. 
is there a way to do this or is it possible through the facebook api?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is [Facebook Grap API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Check this [Graph API - Group](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Hope this help!